# NoSuchElementException: None.get in play framework for scala

Tags: scala, playframework, crud, slick

I need to build update method, but when i test show the error NoSuchElementException: None.get

UserController

```
   object UserController extends Controller {

   def update(id:Long) = DBAction {  implicit rs =>

   var user = simpleUserForm.bindFromRequest.get

   user.id = Users.toOption(id)
   Users.update(user)
   Redirect(routes.UserController.list)
   }

   val simpleUserForm :Form[User] = Form {
     mapping(
       "firstName" -> nonEmptyText,
       "lastName" -> nonEmptyText,
       "email" -> email,
       "birthDate" -> nonEmptyText,
       "phone" -> nonEmptyText,
       "username" -> text,
       "password" -> nonEmptyText
     )(UserForm.fromSimpleForm)(UserForm.toSimpleForm)
   }

 }
```

edit.scala.html

```
@import models.auth.Users
@(title: String, user:models.auth.User)

@main(title){

<form method="post" action="@controllers.auth.routes.UserController.update(Users.toLong(user.id))">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName" value="@user.firstName"/><br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName" value="@user.lastName"/><br/>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="@user.email" /><br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Phone" name="phone" value="@user.phone" /><br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Birthdate(dd/MM/yyyy)" name="birthDate" value="@user.birthDate" /><br/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="username" value="@user.username" /><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Update User" />
</form>
}
```

routes

```
POST        /user/:id/         controllers.auth.UserController.update(id:Long)
```

I already done for create, read and delete, but for update i found error in line
    var user = simpleUserForm.bindFromRequest.get

the error is NoSuchElementException: None.get

Comment: Using `.get` on a `Form` is not safe. It's throwing an exception because there are validation errors, and it therefore cannot bind to an object.

Comment: what i should to use?

Comment: You should use fold instead of .get
`formMapping.feeForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => {
       ???
      },
      dataOnSuccess => ???
      )
  }`

Answer (score 2):

The [Play page on Scala Forms](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaForms) is helpful here. That approach would be to send the populated form to the view as a parameter, then on submit use `fold`, which gives you options to deal with the error case as well as the "happy" case. Something like the following (adapted from the above page):

```
simpleUserForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
  formWithErrors => {
    // binding failure, you retrieve the form containing errors:
    // in your form, test .hasErrors
    BadRequest(views.html.user.edit(formWithErrors))
  },
  userData => {
    /* binding success, you get the value. */
    // .. do the update
    ...
    //-- and return to list or home or...
    Redirect(routes.Application.home(id))
  }
)
```

If you don't want to use the form, then to back to your actual question, would `.getOrElse` not work?

Answer (score 0):

did you import

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
```